# Always loved / Always in my heart in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm getting a tattoo to honor my two living children. Son and daughter. Would semper amari or semper amatus be most appropriate? Or is there another option?

Thank You

Comment: The infinitive passive: "semper amari" = "always to be loved"; the perfect participle passive: "semper amatus" = "always having been loved" ("having been" can be omitted). for two children: plural: "semper amati estis" = "always you (plural) have been loved". The perfect passive tense can function as an aorist or "simple past". Therefore, "amati estis" can be translated as "you (plural) were loved".